# splash screen browser compatibility in html5

Tags: html, browser, compatibility, splash-screen

I have a splash screen on http://brodysfurniture.com/ and it supposed to play music, here is the music embed.

```
<audio  preload="auto" autobuffer autoplay="autoplay"> 
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.mp3" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.ogg" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wav" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.au" />
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.wma" />
<!-- now include flash fall back -->
<source src="http://brodysfurniture.com/wp-content/themes/Brodys/images2/08_Track_8.flv" />
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

The problem is that even with all of these formats ie7 and i believe ie8 do not play the audio element. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `<audio>` or `<video>` elements aren't supported in anything before Internet Explorer 9, so that won't work, and it doesn't understand the audio tag at all.

Where you've listed the Flash fallback, you actually need to put a Flash audio player there, you can't just provide a <source... link to the flv file.

Comment: That is only a problem with IE (as always). Modern browsers, Firefox/Chrome/Opera/etc., have no issues at all and DO support the audio and video elements.

Comment: Great, as for the flash audio player i cannot have a visual player. Any idea on how i would code this player to work properly?